# ASP:NET web api problem with dropdown menu

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, drop-down-menu

I'm making Hotel management web app, and working on part where i need to add rooms ,problem is with dropdown menu, while adding knew code , I don't know why my dropdown menu stopped working ,it wokrked perfectly before but when added another part of code, dropdown just stoped wokring(when i click on it it wont drop), i removed code that i added before but a  dropdown menu still doesent work.I added the part with the dropdown menu below

```
**index.cshtlm**
@model HotelManagement.ViewModel.RoomViewModel
{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}



 <pre>

<div id="divAddRoom" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Room</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="form-group ">
</pre>

                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoomNumber)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RoomNumber, new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtRoomNumber" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoomPrice)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RoomPrice, new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtRoomPrice" })
                </div>

                <div class="form-group ">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookingStatusId)
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BookingStatusId, @Model.ListOfBookingStatus, new { @class = "form-control", id = "ddBookingStatus" })
                </div>

                <div class="form-group ">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoomTypeId)
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoomTypeId, @Model.ListOfRoomType, new { @class = "form-control", id = "ddRoomType" })
                </div>

                <div class="form-group ">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoomCapacity)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RoomCapacity, new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtRoomCapacity" })
                </div>

                <div class="form-group ">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoomDescription)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RoomDescription, new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtRoomDescription" })
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoomImage)
                    <input id="UpLoadImage" type="file" class="form-control" name="roomImage" title="Load Image" onchange="DisplayImage(this)" />
                    <img id="imgRoom" height="200" width="280" style="border:solid" />
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id="btnSave" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Save</button> &nbsp;
            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger">Close</button>


        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Room_controler**

```
    enter code here
  public ActionResult Index(){
        RoomViewModel objRoomViewModel = new RoomViewModel();         
        objRoomViewModel.ListOfBookingStatus = (from obj in objHotelDbEntities.BookingStatus
                                                    select new SelectListItem()
                                                    {
                                                        Text = obj.BookingStatus,
                                                        Value = obj.BookingStatusId.ToString()
                                                    }).ToList();

            objRoomViewModel.ListOfRoomType = (from obj in objHotelDbEntities.RoomTypes
                                               select new SelectListItem()
                                               {
                                                   Text = obj.RoomTypeName,
                                                   Value = obj.RoomTypeId.ToString()
                                               }).ToList();
            return View(objRoomViewModel);
        }
```

[image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMI8Y.jpg)

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem?  Is it that there are no options in the list?  When you debug, are there any elements in `objRoomViewModel.ListOfBookingStatus`?

Comment: Yes there is no options on the list , and I don't know whats the problem because as i already says everything worked perfectly before adding new code, also for  objRoomViewModel.ListOfBookingStatus there are elements in it